# css3 attribute selector based off of class

Tags: css, attributes, selector

I'd like to style a text box within a div that has a specified class:

```
<style>
  .myStyle input[type="text"] {
    width: 250px;
  }
</style>

<div class="myStyle">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

This code doesn't work, is there a way to do this?  (other than assigning a class to the text box itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your CSS, just add `</input>` before the `</div>` and you'll be good to go.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6zmNM/ (With JS to provide an alert for the width of the text box)

Comment: Ugh you guys are right, I'm not sure what I was doing wrong but it's working now.  Thanks for the sanity check.